# How can I `cat` a file as an attachment on a new Thunderbird email message from the command line?

Tags: command-line, thunderbird

As it says on the tin really. I would like to send some of my etc files to a colleague and it would be handy to cat them to a new Thunderbird email message.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: I use `mutt` for this (is a command line mail that can also attach files).

Comment: @Rinzwind I know of `mutt`, but it is too much work to get it setup with the infernal Exchange server we have here at work so I was hoping to be able to use Thunderbird to save on setting it all up in an email client twice! :-) Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, it's working fine for me:

`cat /etc/[file1] /etc/[file2] /etc/[file3] > ~/configs.txt && thunderbird -compose "subject='test',attachment='~/configs.txt'"`

or (a revised command which will also print each filename):

`for file in /etc/[file1] /etc/[file2] ; do echo -e '\n ****' $file '**** \n'  >> ~/configs.txt ; cat $file >> ~/configs.txt ; done && thunderbird -compose "subject='test',attachment='~/configs.txt'"`

Just replace the [fileX] names with the ones you're interested.

The above command will create a new file named `configs.txt` with all of the config files you want and add it as an attachment to a new 'compose mail' window in TB.

Answer (score 3):

I googled «thunderbird command-line», and this first hit seems to be what you want: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_(Thunderbird)

Comment: +1 I didn't think to generalise my query like that. Good find.